# Failed to load contents while calling XMLHttpRequest over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Suppose I have the below URL

```
https://www.somthing.com/shop/AjaxLogonForm?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10151
```

now i have the below JavaScript to fetch the content:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET",document.location.origin,false);
req.send();
```

while execution the above code it throws execption like 'failed to execute Send on XMLHttpRequest'. now if i change the open() as below

```
req.open("GET",document.location.origin,true);
```

then it throws that Mixed content error.
Please suggest how to fetch data in this situation.

Comment: Mixed content problem is occurring when you have page loaded over https, and you js file over http. What url you want to get? because this request will reach https://www.somthing.com only. And where js is located? If it is in the different domain, than you will be blocked by CORS.

Comment: i want to get responseHeader of the request..the JS is located on that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
xmlhttp.open('GET', document.location, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var responseHeaders = xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders();
     }
  }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```